# Laptop power saving or management in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: laptop, power-management

Is there any sort of installation that can be added to provide power options for when I am running on battery? I wouldn't want to always be on power savings, so I would hope I could switch between Eco and performance like I do with windows 7. Anything like this out there?

Answer (score 1):

Install cpu-freq. It has four options: Conservative, Ondemand,Powersave, Performance.
 *(sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq)*